# how to declare a function using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

i did a simple validation script function using javascript, it works, but when i try to do it with jquery it doesnt work, it doesnt call it, i already looked for some tutorial but it seems im not able to do find a clear answer.

Here is the code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () { 

    function validateForm() {
        var cel = document.forms["myForm"]["cel"].value;
        var celconf = document.forms["myForm"]["celconf"].value;
        var ocr=document.forms["myForm"]["ocr"].value;
        var ocrconf = document.forms["myForm"]["ocrconf"].value;



        if (cel==""||celconf==""||ocr==""||ocrconf=="") {
            alert("Todos los campos deben ser llenados");

        }

        else  if (cel.length != 10||celconf.length!=10) {

            alert("El numero celular debe de ser de 10 digitos");}

        else if (cel != celconf) {

            alert("Los numeros celulares ingresados no Coinciden");

        }


       else if (ocr.length<10||ocrconf.length<10) {

            alert("El OCR ingresado no tiene la longitud necesaria, ésta debe de ser de 13 o 10 digitos");

       }

       else if (ocr.length > 13 || ocrconf.length > 13) {

           alert("El OCR ingresado no tiene la longitud necesaria, ésta debe de ser de 13 o 10 digitos");
       }

       else if (ocr.length == 11 || ocr.length == 12 || ocrconf == 11 || ocrconf == 12) {

           alert("El OCR ingresado no tiene la longitud necesaria, ésta debe de ser de 13 o 10 digitos");

       }



       else if (ocr != ocrconf) {

           alert("Los OCR ingresados no Coinciden");

       }

       else {
           $("#myModal").modal("show");
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "http://localhost:38815/altasms/test",
               data: {celjson:cel, ocrjson:ocr},
               success: function(obj) {


                   obj.Celular;
                   obj.OCR;

               }

           });
               return false;


       }



        return false;

    }

    });
```

and here is where i call it, the form:

```
<form style="padding:7px" name="myForm" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()" target="myFrame">
<b>Celular</b><br /><input  onblur="validateCel()" class="form-control" type="number" name="cel"><br />
<br /><b>Confirma tu Celular</b><br /> <input class="form-control" type="number" name="celconf"><br />
<br /><b>OCR</b><br /> <input class="form-control" type="number" name="ocr"><br />
<br /><b>Confirma tu OCR</b><br /> <input class="form-control" type="number" name="ocrconf"><br />
<br /><input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

as i said, it works with js but im trying to make it work with jquery.

Comment: It's out of scope, as it's no longer global, it's inside the DOM ready handlers scope.

Comment: so how do i declare it?

Comment: This might be of use. Will tidy up your code a bit: http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: You only need to run things inside the ready handler if they need to run at that time and need DOM access.  The function can be declared at any point (after jQuery is included), as it is only being called later on, after document.ready.

Comment: What you really should be doing, is getting rid of that inline event handler, and use jQuery for the `submit` event handler as well.

Comment: nit-pick: _" it works with js but im trying to make it work with jquery"_ <== jQ ***is*** JavaScript, if it works, it works, and there's nothing in your code that might cause conflicts with jQ either, it's entirely down to how you declare the function

Comment: so, if im not getting it wrong, i just declare the jquery $(document).ready(function () { }); empty and then my js functions inside my script?

Comment: @Magrangs btw thank yopu very much for that tutorial, thats another issue i had with passive notifications, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`validateForm` doesn't exist outside of this event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function validateForm() {
        // implementation
    }
});
```

So nothing outside of that event handler can see it.  In order for other code to use it, define it outside the handler:

```
function validateForm() {
    // implementation
}
```

Comment: so i should declare the function outside the jquery initialization?? not getting it

Comment: @GregorioMerazJr.: It's perfectly simple: JS functions have their own, closed (sort of) scope. What you declare inside of a function does not exist outside of that function. Your jQ code starts with `$(document).ready(FUNCTION() { /* everything here is part of a function */});` so to gain access to your function globally, you'll have to declare it in the global scope, either by moving the declaration outside of the jQ callback, or by writing `window.validateForm = function(){}` (not recommended)

Comment: @GregorioMerazJr.: That's not a "jQuery initialization".  It's the handler for the document's `ready` event.  Declaring a function doesn't need to wait for the document to be ready, so there's no need to put it in there.  You can declare a function anywhere you like.  (Well, you may at most need to declare it after loading the jQuery library if it depends on the existence of that library.)  Basically, you're currently defining the function *inside another function*, which means it's not visible to anything outside of that function.  To make it visible, define it *outside* of that function.

Comment: so, if im not getting it wrong, i just declare the jquery $(document).ready(function () { }); empty and then my js functions inside my script?

Comment: @GregorioMerazJr.: You don't need to create an empty `ready` handler.  If there's nothing to do when the document is ready then you don't need to write code which does nothing.  Not writing any code will accomplish the same task.  Just declare the function that your code is going to use, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend jQuery in order to have a jQuery solution:

```
$.extend({
    myform: new function () { //create a new object inside jQuery
        var _self = this;

        _self.initialize = function (form) {
            $('.btn-success', form).click(function(){
                 if (isValid(form)){
                     submitForm(form);
                 }
                 else alert('Invalid Form');
            });

        };    

        var isValid = function(form){
            //your validation code here
            //return false if not valid, true otherwise
            return true;
        };   

        var submitForm = function(form){         
           var cel = $('input[name=cel]', form).val();
           var ocr = $('input[name=ocr]', form).val();
           $("#myModal").modal("show");
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "http://localhost:38815/altasms/test",
               data: {celjson:cel, ocrjson:ocr},
               success: function(obj) {
                   console.log(obj.Celular);
                   console.log(obj.OCR);
               }
           }); 
    }
});

$(function () {  //initialize on document ready
    $.myform.initialize($('form[name=myForm]'));
});
```